# Scroll-snap-behaviour property is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to have a page that scrolls horizontally and with each mouse scroll it stops on each section.
I've found a Jquery that is perfect for the horizontal scroll but however the scroll-snap-behaviour property doesn't seem to work.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa_ab/pen/WNLQXrd)

```
 <div class="container" >
   <div class="finestra">
        <h2>1</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="finestra">
        <h2>2</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="finestra">
        <h2>3</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="finestra">
        <h2>4</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
    width: 400vw;
    height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    position: absolute;
    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
}

.finestra{
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```